# Calculate date of birth from age in SAS

Tags: date, sas

This might seem to be a question to which I can check the answer myself. However I am not able to access SAS at the moment. 
My question is this: Can I calculate the date of birth based on the date of death and the age at death? 
If I e.g. want to select the births between 2012 and 2013 is it possbile to do the following:

```
data new_data;
 set old_data;
 where "01Jan2012"d le date_of_death-age le "31Dec2012"d; 
run;
```

Would that do the intended selection based on births from 2012-13?

Best regards

Edit: We assume the age variable to be measured in days..

Answer (score 0):

It should be rather like this:

```
data new_data;
 set old_data;
 where year(date_of_death) - age = 2012; 
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But shouldn't the year function be around the entire expression as in:     year(date_of_death-age) in (2012, 2013)    ?

Comment: Maybe I should add that I suppose (i.e we assume) the age variable to be measured in days - but I don't know since I do not have the data (yet)..